# How to access a view controller that is not the root view controller from AppDelegate.swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I think this is a beginner question. I currently have two view controllers:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    var markersToDelete = Marker()
    func deleteMarkers() {}
}

class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    var markersToDelete = Marker()
    func deleteMarkers() {}
}
```

The `MapViewController` is instantiated with a modal segue in the storyboard. I know that I can access `MainViewController` in `AppDelegate.swift` with this code:

```
var mainViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! MainViewController
```

How can I do the same thing with `MapViewController`?

**EDIT**

Based on the comments below I am updating this to include more detail. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have IBActions in both view controllers that appends Marker items to the
markersToDelete array. The method deleteMarkers is used to find the corresponding items in the Core Data persistent store and delete them; it is called by AppDelegate when applicationDidEnterBackground or when applicationWillTerminate.

This is the reason why I want to access both view controllers from app delegate. I am starting to think there could be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other answers suggest ways of insantiating the controller, but they seem incorrect since you mentioned the controller is instantiated through a segue. There is no straight forward way of doing what you want, and for a good reason, it should be hard to access things from unrelated code. In your very simple example, this code would work, given the controllers have already been presented:

```
var mainViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! MainViewController
let mapViewController  = mainViewController.presentedViewController
```

But I would strongly discourage this type of code inside `AppDelegate`, it makes a lot of assumptions and will break easily if your navigation structure changes. Be more specific about what you're trying to achieve and you may get answers that lead you to a better architecture.

**EDIT**

Given the new information provided by the asker, this is a proposed solution to the more specific problem:

I understand you have `Marker` objects in your Core Data context, and you wish to batch delete some of them. What about adding a bool property to  `Marker` class, and setting it to true for the objects you wish to delete. Then, in `AppDelegate`, you fetch the markers which have that property set to true, and delete them. This way you don't need to mantain an array, and there is no coupling between classes.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm new to stackoverflow, how is this a bad answer?

Comment: I think your answer is the only correct one so far. The others create new view controllers, *not* the one that is on the storyboard so they are totally different from the view controller on the storyboard

Comment: @LeonardoYvens I updated my question to include more detail to show you what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @flightsimmer668 Nice, I've edited my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: @LeonardoYvens That actually sounds like a very great and simple idea. I'm going to go ahead and try it now. In the meantime I took a reference from MapViewController to MainViewController.markersToDelete and append the data there. Then I call MainViewController.deleteMarkers() from AppDelegate. Would that be good practice?

Comment: It's definitely better than having AppDelegate manage everything! But from an MVC stand point, I think you're relying too much on controllers to handle model information. 'markersToDelete' sounds like something that belongs in the model layer.

Comment: @LeonardoYvens I went ahead and implemented what you suggested and it seems to work just fine for both view controllers. I never even thought to incorporate that into the core data model.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your map controller by calling it's storyboard ID, which you'll need to set in Storyboard. Then just do:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
var mapViewController = storyboard. instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardID") as! MapViewController
```

Comment: Would this accomplish the same thing? var mapViewController = MapViewController()

Comment: no. The one you just wrote would only instantiate your class, it would not have anything you created in Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set storyboard  ID to your `mapViewController`. Then You can access it from `appDelegate`.

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
var destViewController : UIViewController
destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewController") as! UIViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by encapsulating your code which is responsible for interaction with CoreData framework API.

Create a singleton class like below and use this class only for insertion/deletion/update operations. This way will ensure loose coupling among your view controllers .

You can get reference to the `sharedInstance` of `DataManager` in any class. . Using `sharedInstance` you can call methods related to your Database operations.

```
class DataManager {
        class var sharedInstance : DataManager {
            struct Singleton {
                static let instance = DataManager()
            }
            return Singleton.instance
    }
    func deleteMarkers() {
    //Your logic here
}
    }
```